# Detecting if browser or CEF/Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium-embedded

Is there a way I can detect if my JS code is running inside a real browser or inside a toolkit like CEF or Electron?

Comment: Probably there are a lot of small differences in the environment that you could consult, but why do you care? Use feature detection.

Comment: I care because the web app I’m working on should show/hide certain buttons only when inside CEF.

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over the app hosting the CEF control you can register an object to be bound, like below:

```
chromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("boundAsync", new CefCustomObject(chromeBrowser), true);
```

CefCustomObject class:

```
class CefCustomObject
{
    // Declare a local instance of chromium and the main form in order to execute things from here in the main thread
    private static ChromiumWebBrowser _instanceBrowser = null;

    public CefCustomObject(ChromiumWebBrowser originalBrowser)
    {
        _instanceBrowser = originalBrowser;
    }
}
```

You can then can check for the existance of this object in the web app.
javascript in web app:

```
(async function()
{
    if ("CefSharp" in window) {
        await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("boundAsync");

        if (boundAsync) {
            alert('running inside CEF')
        }
    }
})();
```

Sources:

- https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application
- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2246

Answer (score 1):

Because the user-agent in an Electron app is like this :

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) websat/0.0.1 Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Electron/2.0.0 Safari/537.36

You can try this :

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Electron') !== -1) {
    console.log('Electron app');
    }
else {
    console.log('not in Electron app');
    }
```